# How do I open a Google OAuth 2.0 consent screen in a local Python code?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-colaboratory, gspread

How do I get Google OAuth 2.0 authorization using a [consent screen](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) in my local Python code?

In my Google Colab notebook, I can easily accomplish this too, for example, access my Google Sheets, with

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.colab import auth
import gspread

auth.authenticate_user()
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
```

which opens the Google Colab consent screen in my browser, where I log in to the account where my sheet is located and get a token that I paste in response to a prompt.

How do I open my consent screen in a local Jupyter notebook or code? Is there an equivalent to the above flow that will launch the consent screen, allow me to authenticate there, collect a (temporary) token, and paste it in response to a presented prompt?

Answer (score 1):

`google.colab` libraries aren't available outside of Colab.

The `gspread` docs have a description for how to authenticate with the library generally:
https://github.com/burnash/gspread#basic-usage

Reproducing the relevant snippet:

1. Obtain OAuth2 credentials from [Google Developers Console](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html)
2. Start using gspread:

   ```
   import gspread
   gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
   ```

Most of the work is going through the cloud project creation process described in the link.

Comment: That's just restating the question, which is what the process of opening the consent screen looks like in Python.